# Laravel Dynamic Form Submit not responding

Tags: ajax, forms, laravel, dynamic, submit

I have a controller ( Laravel ) which will be dynamic create a form as below

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;margin-top:20px;">
  <div class="col-2">   
  <form class="addform" id="newcheckform" role="form">
        '.csrf_field().'  
    <label class="" for="cust_code">Cust Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_code" value="'.$row->cust_no.'">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="" for="cust_short">Cust Shortname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_short">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label class="" for="cust_name">Cust Name</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_name" value="'.$row->cust.'">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
        <label class="" for="region">Region</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="region">
  </div>  
  <div class="col-2">
        <label class="" for="region">Add Cust Data</label>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"  id="createnewcust" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
  </div>  
</div>
```

if will be loaded by below script in the blade file

```
$("#custcheck").load("{{ url('/sales/admin/custcheck') }}");
```

The form displayed as its should to be.
However I when I submit button. Nothing happened. code as below. Appreciate anyone can help. this script resides in the same blade file.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit', '#newcheckform', function(e){
        alert("Hi"); 
    });
});
```

Comment: You have wrong closing tags for form. You initiated `<form>` inside a div and closed at the end outside the `div` Check it first

Comment: Sorry but I couldn't get you that. what is the right way to initiate it?

Comment: Got it right now, Such a simple and easy mistake to me. I relocate the form to the top and close in at the bottom of the div.

Comment: Okay, then close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have wrong closing tags for `<form>` change something like this:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-bottom:30px;margin-top:20px;">
  <form class="addform" id="newcheckform" role="form">
    {{csrf_field()}}  
  <div class="col-2">   
    <label class="" for="cust_code">Cust Code</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_code" value="{{$row->cust_no}}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="" for="cust_short">Cust Shortname</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_short">
  </div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <label class="" for="cust_name">Cust Name</label> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cust_name" value="{{$row->cust}}">
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="" for="region">Region</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="region">
  </div>  
  <div class="col-2">
    <label class="" for="region">Add Cust Data</label>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-info"  id="createnewcust" type="submit">Create</button>
  </div>  
  </form>
</div>
```

This will work.

Comment: Great, Congrats